# How to get total network usage in terminal since pc opened

Tags: command-line, networking, bash, kde, ifconfig

I can get total network usage from terminal by `ifconfig wlp0s20f3` but i also get many other extra info about **wlp0s20f3** device.

The output:

```
wlp0s20f3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.43.67  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.43.255
        inet6 fe80::5f55:a45c:b66a:a7d2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 48:f1:7f:f3:15:83  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 82724  bytes 108476705 (103.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28959  bytes 3840172 (3.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I only need **103.4 MiB** for rx  and **3.6 MiB** for tx to use together with [command output](https://store.kde.org/p/1166510/) plasmoid in kde panel.  How can i get that?

PS: Any bash script to parse ifconfig output or any application gives that values are acceptable

Comment: `ip -s link` would probably be the modern way to get the interface counters.  That would still require parsing.  This discussion might be useful: https://serverfault.com/questions/533513/how-to-get-tx-rx-bytes-without-ifconfig

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The more obvious route is to use Grep to extract only the values.

  ```
  # RX bytes
  ifconfig wlp0s20f3 | grep -o '[0-9.]* MiB' | head -n1
  # TX bytes
  ifconfig wlp0s20f3 | grep -o '[0-9.]* MiB' | tail -n1
  ```
- A more elegant alternative is to fetch the values (in bytes) from the `/sys/class/net/wlp0s20f3/statistics/` directory.

  ```
  cat /sys/class/net/wlp0s20f3/statistics/rx_bytes
  cat /sys/class/net/wlp0s20f3/statistics/tx_bytes
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can get **s**tats (including TX/RX byte and packet counts) in **h**uman readable units from the `ip link` command:

```
ip -s -h link show
```

To restrict output to a specific device use the `dev` field:

```
$ ip -h -s link show dev wls1
3: wls1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:21:6a:96:40:12 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast
    4.52G      5.03M    0       1       0       0
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns
    357M       2.16M    0       0       0       0
```

It's not the easiest output to parse robustly but you could probably use something like

```
$ ip -s -h link show dev wls1 | 
    awk '/RX: bytes/{getline; printf "RX: %s, ", $1} /TX: bytes/{getline; printf "TX: %s\n",$1}'
RX: 4.52G, TX: 357M
```

Replace `wls1` with your own interface name `wlp0s20f3` .

Answer (score 0):

An addition to **[@Quasimodo](https://askubuntu.com/users/832813/quas%C3%ADmodo)** 's answer:

```
echo "Down: $(($(cat /sys/class/net/wlp0s20f3/statistics/rx_bytes)/1024/1024)) MiB, Up: $(($(cat /sys/class/net/wlp0s20f3/statistics/tx_bytes)/1024/1024)) MiB"
```

gives excatly what i want. (wlp0s20f3) is my device.

Result:

```
Down: 103 MiB, Up: 4 MiB
```